# Efficient bit checking in embedded C Program

Tags: embedded, avr

I am using AVR controller atmega328.
I need to check the status of two bits. I have two approaches, but not sure which one is most efficient. In first case in the code below, I am reading the port using PIND command twice (Two times PIND access is made). So is this an issue or I have to go with second if statement?

```
#define SW1 2
#define SW2 5
//check if both are high
if((PIND&(1<<SW1))&&(PIND&(1<<SW2))) 
//Or
if((PIND&((1<<SW1)|(1<<SW2)))==((1<<SW1)|(1<<SW2)))
```

Comment: Please note that the program memory is same in both the cases. I checked the output in Atmel Studio

Comment: your both preprocessors are `SW1`, it wont give you expected result

Comment: Oh sorry, one should be SW2. Did not notice the error. Thanks for bringing it out. Correcting it.

Comment: Why are you worried about efficiency of this operation?  Either way, it should only be about 4-6 instructions.  If the speed of this will make or break your overall system performance, you're doing something wrong...

Comment: if there is a difference I would also suspect it is due to reading the peripheral twice which I would expect to be a longer cycle than ram reads.  how slow is the flash though (fetches) assuming the two read one takes more instructions.  I would think overall the latter one takes less instructions and less time...Just time it though try each for 100000 loops and see which takes longer, not a fool proof test, but may give a lean toward one or the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose `PIND` is a peripheral register (what do you mean by "command"?).

The first check will read it once or twice, depending on the first comparison. This might generate a glitch, if SW1 changes between the first and second read.

Presuming SW? are switches: In general, it is better to read such a register once (possibly to a variable) and test for the bits. That ensures you get a snapshot of all input bits **at the same time**.

Also, the seconde version is not necessarily slower, as it safes a branch (IIRC AVR has no conditional instructions other than branch/jump).

Comment: `switches: [reading such once] ensures you get a snapshot of all input bits at the same time` - which protects against "switch change hazards". If you do **software de-bounce** (e.g., with push buttons), just do it first.

Comment: 1. debounce 2. put value elsewhere to manipulate - not evaluate some intricate condition over and over until stable for the chosen period of time.

Comment: @greybeard: Just comment to the question; it is mal-directed to my answer, as I do not even tread debouncing here (but might be a good note to the OP). You still had to read all inputs in parallel and debounce both switches together (i.e. use a dead-time which restarts if any input changes). However, that code aboved might be very well not need debouncing, e.g. read flags after reset from configuration switches (no bouncing). Still highly speculative.

Answer (score 3):

The first reads PIND twice so is less efficient and a potential for error - the time between reads may be significant if interrupts or thread context switches intervene.

The second evaluates `(1<<SW1)|(1<<SW2)` twice, but in this case it is a compile time constant, so should have no impact on performance. But to be honest you are probably sweating the small stuff worrying too much about the code at this level. If you really need to know; take a look at the code the compiler generates (in the debugger disassembly or by getting the compiler to output an assembly listing), but it will take a long time to write code if you intend to second guess every line like this,

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to say which of the above 2 will be more efficient without the output of assembler. However i would guess that the difference in performance would be very little.

In case 2 you are avoiding reading the registers twice but you are performing 2 additional operations.

If i were to make a guess i would say that option 1 would most likely to be faster since PIND is a AVR regsiter and the cost of reading would be less.

Having said that i would suggest using the first option as its more readable even its not found to be faster than option 2.

Comment: It's not hard to tell at all. Port registers are volatile so reading them twice in the same expression is a bad idea. And in the second case everything gets evaluated at compile-time before the port read.